# Performing a GROUP BY and obtaining an additional column not used in an aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below code I have two tables. I join these, perform a GROUP BY on "Spot" and then a MIN() on a value calculated via the join.

The problem is that I also wish to obtain the value of Column2 for my resultant rows. At the moment I cannot select this immediately because Column2 is not part of the GROUP BY and it is not part of an aggregate function.

Also, I cannot perform a 3rd JOIN on the data to get this column, because I will just end up going around in circles, as my join condition would be on DerivedValue and in order to get this I will need to produce another GROUP BY..... and I will go around in circles.

If it helps to understand- temp4 is just a table containing 1s and 0s, performing a mask (hence the MIN() is done on the multiplication of these two).....

EDIT: Please note, the reason why I am joining the same table is because I am effectively subtracting two values from a matrix and it was the easiest way to get the correct values all in one row to subtract.

```
SELECT temp3.Column1, min(temp3.DerivedValue * Probability) FROM
    (SELECT temp1.Spot AS Spot, temp1.Vol AS Vol, temp1.Value- temp2.Value AS DerivedValue FROM
        (SELECT Spot, Vol, Value FROM My_Table_1) temp1
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT Spot, Vol, Value FROM My_Table_1) temp2
    ON temp1.Spot = temp2.Spot) temp3
JOIN
    (SELECT Spot, Vol, Probability FROM My_Table_2) temp4
ON temp3.Spot = temp4.Spot AND temp3.Vol = temp4.Vol
GROUP BY temp3.Spot
```

Comment: I think it would help if you just list the tables and column names you have then explain what the result set should look like.  Deciphering the query you provided is making my brain hurt.

Comment: @Omtara, is that better?

Comment: I meant that you explain with no SQL what are the tables you have and columns in each, then say which columns you want in the result set.  (e.g. TABLES: Table1 has columnA, columnB  and Table2 has columnX, columnY, etc...  / JOINS: Table1.columnA = Table2.columnY, etc...  / RESULT: Table1.columnA, min(Table1.value-Table2.value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant select a column not present in either in the GROUP BY clause or aggregation. The reason is that there is no way to compress values from multiple rows into one data cell. For example if you group 20 rows into one, how to decide which value to select into the result in this row? You should instruct the query to select the right value, either with grouping on it, or aggregating somehow.

Otherwise it can't be done. Maybe consider to rephrase your question to get some workaround for your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2005 you can use `row_number() over()` the get the column data that is on the same row as a max or min value.

Something like this might work for you. Partition on `temp3.spot` and order by your calculated value. That give you a `row_number` of 1 for the min calculated value. You need to put the entire query in a derived table or a CTE because it is not possible to use `row_number` in a where clause.

```
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT temp3.Spot,
         temp3.DerivedValue * temp4.Probability AS DerivedValue_Probability,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY temp3.spot ORDER BY temp3.DerivedValue * temp4.Probability) as RN
  FROM   (SELECT temp1.Spot                AS Spot,
                 temp1.Vol                 AS Vol,
                 temp1.Value - temp2.Value AS DerivedValue
          FROM   (SELECT Spot,
                         Vol,
                         Value
                  FROM   My_Table_1) temp1
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT Spot,
                                    Vol,
                                    Value
                             FROM   My_Table_1) temp2
                   ON temp1.Spot = temp2.Spot) temp3
         JOIN (SELECT Spot,
                      Vol,
                      Probability
               FROM   My_Table_2) temp4
           ON temp3.Spot = temp4.Spot
              AND temp3.Vol = temp4.Vol
)
SELECT Spot,
       DerivedValue_Probability
FROM C
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a complicated query to give a simple result. Your initial join produces copies of each (Spot,Vol) pair with every difference between two Value values for that pair.

The possible probabilities for a (Spot,Vol) pair are only 0 or 1, thus the minimum you seek is either 0 or 1 times the smallest of these Value differences.

The smallest Value difference for a (Spot,Vol) pair is necessarily min(Value) - max(Value) for that pair.

The simple query below should give you the same result as your posted query. However, it's possible you want something completely different, and your posted query might be wrong.

```
select
  V.Spot, V.Vol, min(P.Probability)*(min(V.Value)-max(V.Value)) as minDVtimesProb
from My_Table_1 as V
join My_Table_2 as P
on P.Spot = V.Spot
and P.Vol = V.Vol
group by V.Spot, V.Vol;
```